# Comparing 2 lists in python, using wildcards

Tags: python, mysql

I am using pymysql to pull database table results as stated below, one table has a list of non-fqdn, the other fqdn. Essentially I want to validate weather or not the partials exist in the full fqdn table - and if so, make a DB insert. Any help would be appreciated. See below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                               
'''Produce list of machines that are postivie matches for rhn and vmware member\
ship'''

import os
import pymysql
import glob

conn = pymysql.connect(host='10.0.0.101', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db\
='hosts')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT hostname from rhnreg")
rhnreg = []
for r in cur.fetchall():
    rhnreg.append(r)

cur.close
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT hostname from metalreg")

mreg = []
for r in cur.fetchall():
    mreg.append(r)

cur.close
conn.close
```

Comment: Show samples of the data and the results you're trying to get. It seems like you should be able to do this with a JOIN in the query, you probably don't have to do it in Python.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports string pattern matching and querying by default, so that should be what you use (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html for more information about these)

This would result with something looking like

```
SELECT hostname FROM fullyqualifiedhostnames where hostname LIKE "%non-qualified-hostname%";
```

Along with this, make sure you actually call the close functions (in the example above you are only "referencing" the actual function's, not calling them. Python has strict parens for calls (e.g. `cur.close()` and `conn.close()`)

Most likely if you want to do this in-python, you can use regex for this (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). One other possible option, is to just use the `fnmatch` built-in library, which will give you UNIX-like file-wildcards which  may be good enough for your use case (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html)